# Search and replace using Regular Expressions in Sublime Text: replace text before search text

Tags: html, regex, replace, sublimetext2

So this would be my Sample:

```
In Kenya since 2010 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDTGpMJi0OI&list=PLqGkpApxFsX8k8ENdCr-9v8iRa2q5jXaE&" onclick="yt.www.watch.player.seekTo(2*60+48);return false;">2:48</a> 
Where comes from: Bukavu <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDTGpMJi0OI&list=PLqGkpApxFsX8k8ENdCr-9v8iRa2q5jXaE&" onclick="yt.www.watch.player.seekTo(3*60+29);return false;">3:29</a>
She would have been killed <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDTGpMJi0OI&list=PLqGkpApxFsX8k8ENdCr-9v8iRa2q5jXaE&" onclick="yt.www.watch.player.seekTo(5*60+15);return false;">5:15</a>
```

now the times m:ss (like **2:48**) should stay where they are, but ALSO be appended to the link that comes **before** it, after the "&" and in the following format: **2:48** should become **t=2m48s**

So, at the end, the whole thing should look like this (check the end of the links)

```
In Kenya since 2010 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDTGpMJi0OI&list=PLqGkpApxFsX8k8ENdCr-9v8iRa2q5jXaE&t=2m48s" onclick="yt.www.watch.player.seekTo(2*60+48);return false;">2:48</a> 
Where comes from: Bukavu <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDTGpMJi0OI&list=PLqGkpApxFsX8k8ENdCr-9v8iRa2q5jXaE&t=3m29s" onclick="yt.www.watch.player.seekTo(3*60+29);return false;">3:29</a>
She would have been killed <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDTGpMJi0OI&list=PLqGkpApxFsX8k8ENdCr-9v8iRa2q5jXaE&t=5m15s" onclick="yt.www.watch.player.seekTo(5*60+15);return false;">5:15</a>
```

Now I found out, i could use **\d:..** to find the times, but I have no Idea on how to proceed or if it is possible at all with sublime text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2:**

I swear I checked on YouTube, and I was able to go to a video with `&t=h5m10s` and it would work as `0:05:10`.  If you need this to be `5m10s` or `0h5m10s`, you'll need to do two different expressions (since Sublime Text won't let you do complex callback functions on your regex replace).

*To replace [`h:mm:ss`](http://regex101.com/r/xG1tC8):*

```
href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(\d*):(\d{2}):(\d{2})

href="$1&t=$3h$4m$5s"$2>$3:$4:$5
```

*To replace [`m:ss`](http://regex101.com/r/hR4pI3):*

```
href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(?!:\d)

href="$1&t=$3m$4s"$2>$3:$4
```

The only unusual syntax that needs explanation is `(?!:\d)`. The `?!` syntax is for a "negative lookahead". This means that the match group will not be followed by an additional `:\d`, otherwise this would match hours/minutes/seconds.

---

**Update:**

Here is an [updated expression for matching optional hours](http://regex101.com/r/zD0zX9).  I double checked and you are able to use `&t=h##m##s` (i.e., a blank hour if it is not matched).  This means we can do one search/replace and just have a blank capture for the hour if it does not exist (you'll see what I mean in a second).

Match this:

```
href="(.*?)"(.*?)>((?:(\d*):)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}))
```

And replace with:

```
href="$1&t=$4h$5m$6s"$2>$3
```

Things got a little more complicated here. Lets take a closer look at the part that changes:

```
(            # start an overarching capture group
  (\d*):?    # capture 0+ digits followed by an optional : (hours)
  (\d{1,2}): # capture 1-2 digits followed by a : (minutes)
  (\d{2})    # capture the last 2 digits (seconds)
)            # end the capture group
```

Now you may wonder why I used that overarching capture group.  This is because we need a way to keep the contents of the anchor link the same.  If we didn't use this, we would have to replace it with `hour:minute:second` and hour may be blank (meaning `3:45` would be replaced with `:3:45`).

---

You can match this:

```
href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(\d)+:(\d{2})
```

And replace it with

```
href="$1&t=$3m$4s"$2>$3:$4
```

How this works is it first finds any anchor's href, while capturing the contents in the *first* capture group.  Then we capture everything up to the `>` in a second capture group.  Next we capture 1+ digit (*third* capture), followed by `:`, and finally capturing the last 2 digits (*fourth* capture).

We essentially replace this with all the same content, but make sure to append `&t=$3m$4s` to the end of the link.  You can see a working example on [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mY2hO8).

Comment: You should be able to use this as a regex find/replace in Sublime Text just like this.  If it doesn't work, let me know..there may be something special about how Sublime Text handles captured groups.

Comment: Absolutely great! I use this by the way to copy and fix youtube descriptions that containe time-links in them. (they are broken when you copy them) What I do is I copy them to dreamweaver in design view, then go to code view and apply your search-and-replace. Works perfectly.

Comment: Sadly, I realized it only works as long the minutes are not more than one digits. so it works for 6m23s but when its 16m23s it will just ignore the **1**. Any solution for that? Best would be it would also be able to deal with this format 1:16:23 and turn it into **1h16m23s** at the end of the link?

Comment: When I use youre last suggestion, it will turn **16:12** into **1h6m16s**. It does work for when I have times that are longer than an hour, but it messes up the times that are shorter than an hour.

Comment: @TobiasH, whoops! On my phone so can't easily update my answer, but [check this out](http://regex101.com/r/sF5sU9)

Comment: thanks we are almost there I think, problem is a format like **h16m12s** is not working. however, **0h16m12s** does work! So is there a way that, whenever there no hours, replace that with a 0 ? Then it would work!

Comment: at least in my country that youtube thing didnt work. thanks however a lot for all the working. I combined the "hour-replace" now, and after that a second where I just replaced **h:** with **0h:** Worked like a charm :)

Comment: No problem, you may want to replace `t=h:` with `t=0h:`, so you don't replace `5h:` with `50h:` :)

Comment: actually thats what I did. Me and my unprecise comments :)